# Accesss Violation Reading Location (critical problem)

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, argv, image-stitching

I'm using this project: https://github.com/johnalthom13/VideoMosaicking

And when I try to use, I got Accesss Violation Reading Location.
**I pointed the line that give Accesss Violation Reading Location.**

*Why I'm getting this error, I can't understand*

Comment: What location was it reading? These values (or values close) can tell you something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations/127404#127404

Comment: @drescherjm **Exception thrown at 0x12CAC893 (opencv_world343d.dll) in VideoMosaicking.exe: 0xC0000005: Accesss Violation Reading Location 0x00000000**

Comment: That is a null pointer.

Comment: so what I should do, master yoda @drescherjm? :)

Comment: Figure out what pointer is `0x00000000` in the debugger when the crash happens.

Comment: how can I figure out with myself? can you describe more? please

Comment: Are you doing this in Visual Studio? If so press retry to break into the debugger when the access violation happens. Then mouse over the variables in that line.

Comment: @drescherjm yes sir Vs 2017

Comment: @drescherjm **I looked AUTOS. it's writing like that:**

Comment: I expect the problem is `matcher_` is a null pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm   **owner 0x00000000 <NULL> cv::details:PtrOwner***

Comment: And @drescherjm **stored 0x00000000 <NULL> cv::DescriptorMatcher***

Comment: @drescherjm did i find the things what you said?

Comment: @drescherjm **owner and stored under the matcher_**

Comment: I think the problem is in whatever code that constructs a Stitcher

Comment: You're creating the `Stitcher` with a null matcher. Start looking at where you create it to find out where that null pointer comes from.

Comment: @drescherjm this is the Stitcher code: https://github.com/johnalthom13/VideoMosaicking/blob/master/Stitcher.cpp

Comment: It's not the Stitcher code. Its the code that creates an instance of Stitcher.

Comment: @molbdnilo it's like you say make you a champion of the world in an instant. please can you evaluate the codes.

Comment: @drescherjm so what should I add the code? sir

Comment: It may be right here: https://github.com/johnalthom13/VideoMosaicking/blob/master/VideoMosaicking.cpp#L73 although I am not sure why this would fail.

Comment: @drescherjm so should I make it comment?

Comment: Here is the problem: https://github.com/johnalthom13/VideoMosaicking/blob/master/AlgorithmFactory.cpp#L57 the "FLANN" code is commented out so it returns a null pointer..

Comment: @drescherjm so will I comment out this codes:  **//if (name == "FLANN")
    {
        //return new cv::FlannBasedMatcher();
    }**

Comment: You probably need to uncoment the code. However I am not sure why the author commented it out. Perhaps the code is broken or requires a different version of opencv.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you sir, I want your mail and I can bother you with my many question please :)

Comment: The code is on github. Ask the person that wrote it via raising an issue. Commenting out an if-condition line whose body is already commented out is meaningless. The author did this for a reason; *ask them*.

Comment: This may be the reason for commenting out the code ***TODO Fix linking error*** to me that says the `cv::FlannBasedMatcher();` required an additional library to link and the author disabled the code instead of fixing that. I am no opencv expert so I don't know.

Comment: @WhozCraig I won't ask them

Comment: I'll ask to @drescherjm

Comment: There is no better (or more proper) person to ask than the very author whose code is an otherwise-black-box to you. @drescherjm has done an excellent job of diagnosing the issue; the rest is between you an the author of the code. VTC.

Comment: Pfft. I'm a lot of things. Jealous isn't one of them. I'm impressed @drescherjm went the extra mile, and glad he was able to help. Truly. But his work is done; yours still has work between you and the original author of the library you're consuming. If they truly don't care about your questions, perhaps that is a sign that maybe that isn't the best supported library to be consuming, and you may consider alternatives. Regardless, have a nice day.

Comment: See what happens when you uncomment the two commented out lines. What I mean is replace `//if (name == "FLANN")` with `if (name == "FLANN")` and `//return new cv::FlannBasedMatcher();` with `return new cv::FlannBasedMatcher();` if you get a linker error you need to consult the documentation of opencv on what library to link. I am not sure I can help any more than that.

Comment: ***I'm impressed @drescherjm went the extra mile*** I generally don't go that far if I am at work however today I am home sick so I had extra time. With that said, I am going need some rest..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198015/discussion-on-question-by-hsd-accesss-violation-reading-location-critical-probl).

Comment: @drescherjm thank you sir,:) I fixed the problem. How can I reach you, whenever I want?

Comment: Just ask questions here. I am on StackOverlflow nearly every single day for years.

Comment: As for this question. I would create an official answer but I am not sure how much it will help future readers since it relies on content that is on an outside source. It's too big to move here and if you did just move the parts that I found the answer would be just uncomment the commented out code in the question. Does not sound very useful. Unless someone was using this exact same code on github. We may just want to delete the question. Not sure how others feel.